# Login as another user without View setup and configuration permission

Tags: permissions, configuration, setup, userrecordaccess, grant-login-access

Can an user be given login as another user privileges without giving 'View Setup and Configuration' permission and 'Modify All Permission'?

As the need is  to do testing in sales force logging in with different profiles without having access to the object, fields and other metadatas and configuration in the org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need at least View Setup & Configuration, as there's no "Login" option from anywhere other than the setup screens. You don't need Modify All Data if you're a [Delegated Administrator](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_delegate.htm&type=5) (which also requires View Setup & Configuration). There's little reason to restrict access to View Setup & Configuration, as there's not much you can do without additional permissions.

Comment: The user will have view access to all the apex classes and pages and i don't want the user to access it. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: @MoyeetriPattanaik View Setup & Configuration is required because otherwise you can't see users to login as.